# Can't resolve methods in Java class for Temperature Driver

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, temperature

***I'm having issues properly creating my add() subtract() and divide() method, maybe I'm overthinking it. How would I properly return the needed object. My IDE is saying "Cannot resolve symbol Temperature". Am I calling the 'this' correctly?

***I am aware the add and divide methods are incomplete, if I can receive help on completing the subtract() method everything should fall into place.

```
    import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;

/**
 * Created by Makoto on 2/4/2016.
 */

public class Temperature {
    public double temp;
    public char type;

    Temperature() {
        temp = 0.0;
        type = 'o';

    }

    Temperature( double temperature, char tempType){
            temperature = temp;
            tempType = type;
    }

    public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'C':

                break;

            case 'K':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this.Temperature;
    }

    public Temperature toCelsius() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'F':

                break;

            case 'K':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this.Temperature;
    }

    public Temperature toKelvin() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'C':

                break;

            case 'F':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this.Temperature;
    }

    public Temperature add(Temperature x){

        this.Temperature + x;
        return this.Temperature;
    }

    public Temperature subtract(Temperature x){

        this.Temperature = this.temp - x.temp;
        return this.Temperature;
    }
    public Temperature divide(int x){

        this.Temperature = /x;
        return this.Temperature;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think this statement does: `return this.Temperature`? If you are able to _fully_ explain this statement, you will also be able to spot your mistake.

Comment: Supposed to return the object over into my driver.

Comment: I asked the question with much more detailed Java language explanation in mind.

Comment: My apologies as I am just a intro to CompSci student. I'll rephrase as best I can; The 'return this.Temperature' is suppose to return the Temperature object that is the owner of the method after the subtraction equation has been done to it. In my driver, one Temperature object is the owner of the method and and another Temp Object is being passed through the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return this only.

```
  import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;

/**
 * Created by Makoto on 2/4/2016.
 */

public class Temperature {
    public double temp;
    public char type;

    Temperature() {
        temp = 0.0;
        type = 'o';

    }

    Temperature( double temperature, char tempType){
            temperature = temp;
            tempType = type;
    }

    public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'C':

                break;

            case 'K':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Temperature toCelsius() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'F':

                break;

            case 'K':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Temperature toKelvin() {
        type.equalsIgnoreCase();
        switch (type) {
            case 'C':

                break;

            case 'F':

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Can not convert.");
                break;
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Temperature add(Temperature x){

        this.temp + x.temp;
        return this;
    }

    public Temperature subtract(Temperature x){

        this.temp = this.temp - x.temp;
        return this;
    }
    public Temperature divide(int x){

        this.temp = /x;
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: edited my answeur , you were assigning object to a value. Corrected all of your methods. Now check it will work like a charm

Comment: Hi there. Your answers are very helpful, but please do not add voting commentary to your posts. If people like them, they will upvote them naturally.

Answer (score 0):

`this.Temperature = this.temp - x.temp;` isn't a valid statement in Java. You are trying to set `Temperature`, which itself is not an object, to a value. What you're trying to do here is perform an operation on your `temp` variable, and then return `this`. By returning `this`, the calling object will now have the Temperature object with the updated fields.

For example:

`public Temperature subtract(Temperature x){
        temp = temp - x.temp;
        return this;
}`

The above code will update *this Temperature object's temp*, and then return itself. Then, the calling object can access it by calling `returnedTemperatureObject.temp`.

Comment: Also, take a closer look at what you're doing in your second constructor (the one that is accepting the parameters `temperature` and `tempType`).